# Does Flex/Actionsctipt/Flash implements a mechanism for reusing Sprites?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, performance, sprite

I'm creating a game and I create sprites(enemies). I keep creating and destroying sprites. Flash/Flex has a garbage collector which handles the destruction of unused resources. Should I create an object pool to reuse them, or should I leave flash/flex to handle the creation/destruction of objects?

Which option is better from the performance point of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object Pooling is an excellent idea if you need to create/destroy lots of items.  Flex 4 is [doing this with their DataGroup](http://www.hulstkamp.com/byard/gumbo/DataListTest/DataGroupTest.html) for managing creating destroying itemRenderers while you scroll through huge lists, and it dramatically improves rendering performance.

And all of the [particle frameworks](http://flare.prefuse.org/api/flare/physics/Simulation.html) HAVE to use this to be competitive.

Check out these Object Pooling Demos and Presentations for Actionscript:

- [Object Pooling in AS3](http://www.lostinactionscript.com/blog/index.php/2008/10/30/object-pooling-in-as3/) by Lost in Actionscript.
- [Polygonal Labs' ObjectPool class](http://lab.polygonal.de/2008/06/18/using-object-pools/) and some examples.
- [Object Pools prevent "stuttering"](http://www.electrotank.com/junk/mike/flash/objectpool/) example.
- Grant Skinner describes some bits about [Object Pooling in his Presentation](http://gskinner.com/talks/quickTokyo/#84), among other neat things.

I'd recommend using an object pool if you're creating/destroying lots of objects.  Performance optimizations are very important early on if you're building a complex project and you won't have time to go back to it for a while.  Object Pooling goes a long way and is very easy to implement.

Hope that helps,
Lance

Answer (score 3):

Leave it to the Flash player to handle and only worry about optimisation if there turns out to be a performance problem. Its all hypothetical until then anyway.